# Velocity of a particle whose equation of motion is given

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A particle starts from the origin of coordinates at time t = 0 and moves in the xy plane with a constant acceleration $\alpha$ in the y-direction. Its equation of motion is $y = βx^2$. Its velocity component in the x-direction is

I differentiated the equations both sides

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2\beta x\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$v_y= 2\beta x v_x$$

since we know acceleration along y axis is $\alpha$

$$\frac{v_y}{dt}=2\beta\left(v_x+x\frac{v_x}{dt}\right) $$
$$\alpha=2\beta(v_x+0)$$ (since there’s no acceleration along x axis  given)

therefore

$$v_x= \frac{\alpha}{2\beta}$$

But the correct answer is $\sqrt\frac{\alpha}{2\beta}$
And they have found y and x as a function of time then differentiated to find the velocity. While I understood the method, my question is-

Why can’t we differentiate an equation of motion directly to get the answer. What is the problem while doing so?

Comment: Your time derivative of $v_y$ is incorrect. Try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it by differentiation of the equation of motion. By definition, the expressions for velocity and acceleration and obtained by differentiation of the equations describing the position of an object/particle.

The problem here is that you did not calculate the derivative $\frac{dv_y}{dt}$ correctly. Given the expression you correctly derived for the velocity $$v_y= 2\beta x v_x$$ then $$\frac{dv_y}{dt}=2\beta v_x\frac{dx}{dt}+2x\beta\frac{dv_x}{dt}$$ Note that $$\frac{d}{dt}(x)=\frac{dx}{dt}$$ and does not equal 1. Apparently you took the derivative of $x$ with respect to $x$ and not with respect to $t$

From here, $$\frac{dv_y}{dt}=2\beta v_x\frac{dx}{dt}=2\beta v_x^2$$ since $$\frac{dv_x}{dt}=0$$ and given that $$a_y=\frac{dv_y}{dt}=\alpha$$ then $$\alpha=2\beta v_x^2$$ and so $$v_x=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2\beta}}$$